# Convertir un dataframe en una matriz

Tags: r

Teniendo un dataframe parecido a este (con 245 filas y 3 columnas):

```
per_site_plant_family_abundance:

   Site     Family            Abundance
   L3V      Amaranthaceae      6
   L3V      Brassicaeae        5
   L3V      Malvaceae          13
   L4F      Amaranthaceae      1
   L4F      Polygonaceae       18
```

Me gustaría obtener una matriz como esta:

```
        Amaranthaceae     Brassicaeae   Malvaceae   Polygonaceae
L3V         6                  5           13           0
L4F         1                  0            0          18
```

No encuentro la manera de hacerlo con esta función:

```
  L<-acast(per_site_plant_family_abundance,Site~Family,fill = 0 );dim(L)
```

Alguien me podría explicarme donde está mi fallo.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obtuve mi matriz usando esta función:

```
 prueba<-per_site_plant_family_abundance %>% 
     spread(Family,Abundance,fill = 0)
```